# Access SASS multidimensional list key

Tags: css, sass

I have a multidimensional list:

```
$color-set: (bg-color #888, border-color #444, active-bg-color #666, hover-bg-color #808080)
```

Currently I access each by using:

```
$color-set: (#888, #444, #666, #808080)
#div {
   background: nth($color-set, 1)
}
```

Is there a way to use the key instead like:

```
#div {
   background: $color-set(bg-color)
}
```

so I don't have to remember the order of colors in the list?

Comment: Checkout Maps - which are coming as part of Sass 3.3.0: https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#sassscript-maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have is a list of lists, and lists only have numeric indexes.  You would have to write a function that iterates over your list and compares the first element to some string argument.  This is not something I recommend as it offers no benefit over just using ordinary variables.

```
@function find-value($list, $key) {
    @each $item in $list {
        @if ($key == nth($item, 1)) {
            @return nth($item, 2);
        }
    }
    @return false;
}
```

Sass does not currently support mappings, but will *soon*: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/642

Comment: `$items` should be `$item` on the `@return nth($items, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a separate variable for each color?

```
$bg-color: #888;
$border-color #444;

div {
   background: $bg-color
}
```

Comment: Actually I want these colors to be in one variable to represent a color scheme. Is there a way to achieve it with my desired setup?

Comment: What advantage does that have for you over individual variables?