# SASS Index in nested list

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to get the index of an item in a nested SASS list — by the first property. But the only way i can get a result is to include both properties in the item.

Is is doable with native SASS, or would it require a mixin/function? And any input to how i would do that?

The code i got:

```
$icons : (
  'arrow--down--full' '\e806', /* '' */
  'cog' '\e805', /* '' */
  'info' '\e807', /* '' */
  'arrow--down' '\e800', /* '' */
  'arrow--left' '\e801', /* '' */
  'arrow--right' '\e802', /* '' */
  'arrow--up' '\e803',  /* '' */
  'close' '\e804', /* '' */
  'search' '\e804', /* '' */
  'spin' '\e809' /* '' */
);
```

And my lookup

```
//Working
index($icons, 'search' '\e804');

//Not working, but what i want to achieve
index($icons, 'search');
```

Comment: Where is the code for your index function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access SASS multidimensional list key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995373/access-sass-multidimensional-list-key)

Comment: @cimmanon, the index function is native SASS: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're talking about is a hash or lookup table, which Sass does not currently have. However, you can easily work around that in a variety of ways. Here are some examples.

You could structure your list a little differently:

```
$icons : (
  'arrow--down--full', '\e806', /* '' */
  'cog', '\e805', /* '' */
  'info', '\e807', /* '' */
  ...
);
```

I've added a comma after each item. Now to look it up you'd write a function like

```
@function lookup($list, $key) {
  @return nth( $list, ( ( index($list, $key) ) + 1) );
}
```

And call it like so

```
lookup($icons, 'cog'); // => '\e805'
```

You could push this a little further by making 2 different lists and then associating them via a similar function:

```
$icon-keys:    ('arrow--down--full', 'cog',    'info' ... );
$icon-values:  ('\e806',             '\e805',  '\e807' ... );
```

I've lined up the values with whitespace only to make them more legible to me so that they appear a bit like an actual table, but there are tons of ways of writing Sass lists, and you may prefer another. Then the function that associates them:

```
@function lookup($lookup-key, $all-keys, $all-values) {
  @return nth($all-values, index($all-keys, $lookup-key));
}
```

And using it:

```
lookup('cog', $icon-keys, $icon-values); // => '\e805'
```

For my tastes, these are both a bit clunky so I'd make a shortcut function to make it a bit more legible:

for the first variation:

```
@function icons($lookup-key) {
  @return lookup($icons, $lookup-key);
}
```

for the second:

```
@function icons($lookup-key, $types: $icon-keys, $values: $icon-values) {
  @return lookup($lookup-key, $types, $values);
}
```

so you could just in either case call

```
icons('cog');
```

You'd probably want to put a little more logic in your lookup functions to error catch, and you could also expand it to both accept and return a list rather than a single value, but this is just a basic example.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't restructure the list, i'm using several mixin/functions that's depending on the structure. I'll look into this approach in my next project. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon) answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004655/786123

```
@function find-value($list, $key) {
    @each $item in $list {
        @if ($key == nth($item, 1)) {
            @return nth($items, 2);
        }
    }
    @return false;
}
```